# Can a div keep its aspect ratio within a flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to fit some text and couple of divs in a column flexbox but I fail to follow my requirements.

Requirements are :

- no overflows, divs must stay fully visible with no scroll bars
- divs shall keep their aspect ratio (here 1200 x 400), whatever the containing flexbox size is (here, the flexbox is driven by the viewport).

That means that divs shall shrink vertically or horizontally depending on the flexbox container size (itself sized from the viewport of other reasons).
I understand that with such requirements, content of the divs may be clipped, but that is fine to me.
I basically need to reproduce the image object-fit: contain behavior but on divs, basically [this effect](https://codepen.io/Jean-yves-Leseigneur/pen/JjwKGpG) but without images.

I have tried to play with aspect ratio and flex-basis with 0 success.
The divs do not obey the aspect ratio at all.
Any help is welcome, I'm under water with this.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Jean-yves-Leseigneur/pen/xxmEVRE)

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {

    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.8em;

    height: 100%;
}



.flex-parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    color: black;
    gap: 8px;
    height: 100%;

}


.flex-child {
    flex: 1 1 400px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: 400px;
    
    aspect-ratio: 1200 / 400;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>

</style>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="flex-parent">
        <p>Some text</p>
        <div class="flex-child">

        </div>
        <div class="flex-child">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this could help you: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/aspect-ratio/ and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css

Answer (score 0):

No, but it can in a grid.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html {
  height: 100svh;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.d1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  color: black;
  gap: 8px;
  height: 100%;
  justify-items: center;
}

.d1>* {
  border: 2px solid black;
  aspect-ratio: 3/1;
  padding: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.d1>*:first-child {
  align-self: end;
}

.d1>*>*:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.d1>*>*:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed id dolor dui. Proin consequat neque vestibulum interdum ultrices. Sed ullamcorper felis nec arcu iaculis, eget commodo libero ornare. In imperdiet odio vitae elementum cursus. Cras a blandit enim. Aenean quis convallis risus, in pharetra lacus. Morbi id tellus eget diam sodales elementum et sed massa.</p>
    <p>Integer vestibulum convallis lectus, vitae iaculis risus. Cras aliquet felis vitae ante luctus rutrum. Duis ac placerat elit, in volutpat nisi. Maecenas convallis interdum metus nec tempor. Mauris id libero vestibulum, tincidunt justo sit amet, consequat lorem. Aenean arcu dolor, ornare nec hendrerit ac, elementum vitae tortor. Integer placerat egestas libero, et fermentum tellus mattis eget. Pellentesque ut malesuada dolor. Vivamus ex lacus, dignissim sed quam ut, luctus tempor justo. Etiam ut tortor at nulla iaculis vulputate. Aliquam maximus tincidunt mauris, at malesuada ligula tempor ac. Vivamus pretium, purus in blandit posuere, dolor metus venenatis quam, placerat ullamcorper purus urna ut mi. Suspendisse vitae elit gravida, ullamcorper felis non, posuere dui. Morbi nulla nisi, sollicitudin sit amet tempor eget, rhoncus ut odio. Nam convallis viverra lorem nec auctor.</p>  
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed id dolor dui. Proin consequat neque vestibulum interdum ultrices. Sed ullamcorper felis nec arcu iaculis, eget commodo libero ornare. In imperdiet odio vitae elementum cursus. Cras a blandit enim. Aenean quis convallis risus, in pharetra lacus. Morbi id tellus eget diam sodales elementum et sed massa.</p>
    <p>Integer vestibulum convallis lectus, vitae iaculis risus. Cras aliquet felis vitae ante luctus rutrum. Duis ac placerat elit, in volutpat nisi. Maecenas convallis interdum metus nec tempor. Mauris id libero vestibulum, tincidunt justo sit amet, consequat lorem. Aenean arcu dolor, ornare nec hendrerit ac, elementum vitae tortor. Integer placerat egestas libero, et fermentum tellus mattis eget. Pellentesque ut malesuada dolor. Vivamus ex lacus, dignissim sed quam ut, luctus tempor justo. Etiam ut tortor at nulla iaculis vulputate. Aliquam maximus tincidunt mauris, at malesuada ligula tempor ac. Vivamus pretium, purus in blandit posuere, dolor metus venenatis quam, placerat ullamcorper purus urna ut mi. Suspendisse vitae elit gravida, ullamcorper felis non, posuere dui. Morbi nulla nisi, sollicitudin sit amet tempor eget, rhoncus ut odio. Nam convallis viverra lorem nec auctor.</p>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. With this code the divs do not shrink to adapt to the browser window when browser height is reduced. Thus, vertical scroll bars appears.

Comment: This is a great way of doing it, but I needed the flexbox in the loop.
I believe now that what I want is just not possible in pure CSS.
I will have to go and add some Javascript.